# sql select's using mysql query browser

Tags: sql, mysql, database, table-alias

I am wondering why when I use MySQL Query Browser and double click table names the sql statements look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table t;
```

where t = the first letter of the table... What is the purpose of this letter? I am just curious

Comment: select rltn.* from really_long_table_name rltn -- any clearer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `t` is an alias for the table. It helps when writing queries with :

- many columns in the select list
- (many) joins where writing the full table name would be unreadable

  `Foo f INNER JOIN Customers c on c.ID = f.CustomerID LEFT JOIN BAR b on b.ID=f.ID`
- if you wanted 2+ copies of the same table, you could alias them with different names:

  `Invoices i LEFT JOIN Invoices i2 on i.ID = i2.MasterInvoiceID`
- long table/view names that would be cumbersome to keep writing/reading. Naming conventions sometimes are the culprit. Imagine a data warehouse table like:

  `InvoicesThatAreOverdue_Temp_Holding_20101128`

It's not required, but the MySQL Query Browser is helping promote the use of aliases. Here's hoping it helps developers write readable code!

Comment: @OMG: cheers! Gosh, this answer should really be marked CW ;)

Comment: Thank you for all the great info. I never knew you could leave out the as when using an alias. +1 for the info and making me even more lazy.

Answer (score 3):

It is an alias that will allow you to shorten your references

For example

```
Select * from table1 t1
Inner Join table2 t2 on t1.PK = t2.FK
```

Instead of this

```
Select * from table1 
Inner Join table2 on table1.PK = table2.FK
```

Answer (score 2):

[It is known as alias :)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

> In SQL, an alias name can be given to
>   a table or to a column. You can give a
>   table or a column another name by
>   using an alias. This can be a good
>   thing to do if you have very long or
>   complex table names or column names.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually using a shortcut (alias) to give a new name to the table.

```
// this is the full command but you can leave out AS if you want
SELECT * FROM database.table AS t;
```

Table aliasing is pretty useful for larger queries when you're joining multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

It's a table alias. Here is a [short tutorial](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Table_Aliases.htm) on using aliases.